# print on a printer an order form using javascript or ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, printing

I would like to print on a printer an order form.
I've got this : [image]
The order form will be composed of field which are surrounded.
Everytime i've got a new order i would like to print it. I already have a `header("Refresh:30");. I just need something in javascript or AJAX or jQuery to print it.
All of those datas are on a database, is there a way to print the datas ?

Comment: i didn't try anything yet

Comment: Then don't come here. Don't expect us to write it, try it yourself first.

Comment: I tried to open a new tab to print the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few pointers to help you:

1. Javascript is not designed to work with native system resources like printers, Network cards, etc
2. Activex / Flash (Activex) objects can. This you can control using javascript
3. Consider printing from server or on browser popup (default print view)